# How to uninstall software in Linux 

Tags: linux, fedora, package-management, yum

how to uninstall software in linux. I am facing issues installing No machine setup(NX)

Answer (score 5):

`rpm -e <package>` or `yum remove <package>` if it was installed via a package. Otherwise `make uninstall` or judicious use of `rm`.

Answer (score 3):

If I want to uninstall a program quickly and I only know part of the name I find the following commands always nice.

Lets say I want to remove only tomcat from my system, I use:

> rpm -qa | grep "tomcat" | xargs rpm -e

If I want to remove tomcat and all its dependencies I use:

> rpm -qa | grep "tomcat" | xargs yum erase -y

There are all kinds of variations on these commands, and they can be quite powerful.

Comment: Better do "yum erase /usr/bin/tomcat" in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

`yum remove <package>` As for any details on which packages are installed, you could use `yum list`. That should show all packages.

Answer (score 0):

checkout `yum --help` or `man yum`